# Progress bar not updated using C++ code and GTK+

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtk, progress-bar

Here is my code for a simple progress bar using GTK+ but it seems to be not updating. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.(Fixed the bug by returning g_boolean as TRUE so that the function gets called )

```
 //CodeGoes here
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
#include<cstring>
static float percentage =0.0;

static gboolean inc_prog(gpointer data){
    percentage+=0.05;
    if(percentage>1.0)
      percentage=0.0;
    gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(data),percentage);
    char ch[3];
    sprintf(ch,"%d%%",static_cast<int>(percentage*100));
    gtk_progress_bar_set_text(GTK_PROGRESS_BAR(data),ch);
    return TRUE; //Change Made Here
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
  gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
  GtkWidget *window,*progress;
  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  g_signal_connect(window,"delete-event",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);

  progress=gtk_progress_bar_new();//define instance 

  g_timeout_add(300,inc_prog,progress);//delay of 300 ms
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),progress);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
  gtk_main();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ch` has insuffisient buffer size. It should have at least 5 elements to store `"100%"`.

Comment: You never returned a value from `inc_prog()`. See the documentation of `g_timeout_add()` for details.

Comment: That was helpful .. Thank you  @andlabs

Comment: And now that the answer was given in the comments section, @andlabs, the question is orphaned. Wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

You never returned a value from `inc_prog()`, which is undefined behavior. See the documentation of `g_timeout_add()` for details on what to properly do.